# Swift: If I remove a Value, why removed Firebase this Value again if I insert it again?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I remove a value and try to insert it again, firebase remove this value automatically and I can't insert this value. Why is that and how can I break this issue?

```
ref.child("Matches").child(self.replayUserDepartment).child(DatingController.finalUserID).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
                if snapshot.exists(){
                    for child in snapshot.children{
                        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot

                        if (snap.value as? String) == self.replayUserUid{
                            ref.child("Matches").child(self.replayUserDepartment).child(DatingController.finalUserID).child(snap.key).setValue(nil)

                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

In this Code I set a value that exists to nil because I want to delete this value. After I do this I want to insert the same value that I have removed before. If I do that, Firebase goes there and delete this value automatically without my agreement. And I cannot insert this specific value again.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're seeing.  Could you edit the question and walk through your observations step by step?

Comment: What I understand is in the condition block you are setting the child value to nil "                            ref.child("Matches").child(self.replayUserDepartment).child(DatingController.finalUserID).child(snap.key).setValue(nil)
", that's why it removes from firebase. Create the data object at client side assign value from firebase and play with that data object in your class.

Comment: @RaviSharma The Problem is: I remove a value with setValue(nil). After that I try to insert specially the "removed value" (its the same value) again to the realtime database. After I insert it, Firebase suddenly remove this value automatically. So i can't insert the "removed value" to the database. As Example: Value exists: "er12".setValue("Example") - Value Remove: "er12".setValue(nil) - Insert same Value again: "er12".setValue("Example") - Firebase remove it immediately without my agreement: "er12".setValue(nil)

Comment: @EbuBekirCelik Is above mentioned code is calling in a firebase observer?

Comment: What about using remove or removeValue instead?

Comment: @RaviSharma You made my day! This was the issue! Cause of the observer. I have changed the code and delete it outer the observer and it still works! Thank you man!